# pandas efficient way to drop columns in for-loop

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a list of columns that I want to drop from a dataframe. I don't know if all the columns are present across multiple dataframes, which is why I want to iterate over them and drop the ones that are present. For example:

```
cols = ['one', 'two', 'three']
for col in cols:
    try:
        df = df.drop(col, axis=1)
    except:
        pass
```

Is there a more efficient way to do this that saves time/processing power?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can set `errors='ignore'`:

```
df = df.drop(cols, axis=1, errors='ignore')
```

Alternatively, you can use an index [`intersection`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Index.intersection.html):

```
cols = ['one', 'two', 'three']

df = df.drop(df.columns.intersection(cols), axis=1)
```

Or [`difference`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Index.difference.html):

```
df = df[df.columns.difference(cols)]
```

Comment: Quick test on 1000 columns and a list of 1000 names to delete with 500 common ones: several seconds to run with the loop, few tens of milliseconds with the intersection ;)

Comment: `df[df.columns.difference(cols)]` is also the same speed